# What is the quickest way to check if Apache Flume installation is working?

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I have downloaded and extracted Apache Flume.

How can I check if it's ready to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running the command `bin/flume-ng agent -c conf -f conf/flume-conf.properties.template -n agent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console` in the directory you have extracted the Flume binaries.

It should start with some info messages (classpath and maybe SLF4j warnings), some start-up messages and a lot of lines like:

`2016-10-13 16:48:22,277 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.LoggerSink.process(LoggerSink.java:95)] Event: { headers:{} body: 38 30 32                                        802 }`

Answer (score 3):

To check if Apache-Flume is installed correctly `cd` to your `flume/bin` directory and then enter the command `flume-ng version`.

```
$ cd <flume home directory>/bin
$ flume-ng version
```

Make sure that you are in the correct directory by using the `ls` command. `flume-ng` will be in the output if you are in the correct directory.